# xcodebuild does not generate output files

Tags: ios, continuous-integration, xcodebuild

I have set up a CI iOS workflow (tried BitRise and Travis) for building an xcode **framework**. While I have no problem with iOS Apps, this framework is hard to build. I created a cocoapod lib (with example project) and now I try to archive the lib.

My project has a workspace with several schemes. Since my project uses Vuforia, I cannot test my framework/library on a simulator because that vuforia-library simply does not exists.

I have a build script that I can run without any problems locally on my machine:

xcodebuild archive -workspace Example/MyLib.xcworkspace -scheme "MyLib" -configuration Release -derivedDataPath ./build -archivePath ./build/Products/MyLib.xcarchive -sdk iphoneos ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO -destination generic/platform=iOS | xcpretty -c

The -destination part is crucial since it prevents building for simulator or even i386 platform.

When I run this script on travis or bitrise, I get this result:

```
▸ Archive Succeeded
The command "xcodebuild archive -workspace Example/MyLib.xcworkspace -scheme "MyLib" -configuration Release -derivedDataPath ./build -archivePath ./build/Products/MyLib.xcarchive -sdk iphoneos ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO -destination generic/platform=iOS | xcpretty -c" exited with 0.
```

When I try to find the artifacts, the folders are empty. The build-time for the whole xcodebuild command is 5 seconds and no log output of any compiled file is presented.

This is my script:

```
# references:
# * https://www.objc.io/issues/6-build-tools/travis-ci/
# * https://github.com/supermarin/xcpretty#usage
os: osx
osx_image: xcode11.3
language: swift
# cache: cocoapods
podfile: Example/Podfile
before_install:
  - brew update
  - brew install git-lfs
  - gem install cocoapods
  - pod install --project-directory=Example
before_script:
  - git lfs pull
script:
  - xcodebuild archive -workspace Example/MyLib.xcworkspace -scheme "MyLib" -configuration Release -derivedDataPath ./build -archivePath ./build/Products/MyLib.xcarchive -sdk iphoneos ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO -destination generic/platform=iOS | xcpretty -c
```

I tried clean, build, archive. Always the same result. I tried different version of cocoapods, no success. The build logs shows the exact same output as the console and as shown above. Chaning the derivedDataPath and/or archivePath did not change anything.

No matter what I do, the output is always empty, no files are compiled. Why does it say 'success' but obviously fails?

Thanks for you help,
Jan

Comment: you can add --verbose flag to your run command to get more insight

Comment: I used -verbose and removed the xcpretty. Unfortunately there is no increase in log output.

Comment: you need 2 `-` ie `--verbose` or `-v`

Comment: xcodebuild --verbose
xcodebuild: error: invalid option '--verbose'
Or do you mean the run script from travis?